# Change in macro formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that looks like:

[image]

and I want to make it look like this:

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
   Sub FindString()
   Dim A As Range, r As Range, last As Range
   Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))

   For Each r In A
       If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) Then Set last = r
       If Not last Is Nothing Then last.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
  Next r
 End Sub
```

It works but if the rows are more than 50,000 will hang Excel. So I found some help on this site and changed to:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim r As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

r.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A4,6))),A4,B3)"
r.Offset(0, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Now the trouble is I don't understand what this bit:

```
"=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A4,6))),A4,B3)"
```

in the formula is doing and if in my current formula if I change to if condition:

```
  If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) And 0 = InStr(r, "Totals:")
```

How can I change the similar to sub DEMO() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want faster speed, use something like this instead of the demo code you posted. This code is also more flexible.  The only

```
Sub Demo2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim A() As Variant
    A = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    Dim B() As Variant
    ReDim B(1 To UBound(A), 1 To 1)
    Dim ID As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(A)
        If IsNumeric(Left(A(i, 1), 1)) Then
            ID = A(i, 1)
            'If you want to use a dynamic equation, use the below line instead
            'ID = "=A" & i
        End If
        B(i, 1) = ID
    Next
    Range("B1:B" & UBound(B)) = B
End Sub
```

Comment: How is a loop faster than a `With` block?

Comment: thank you very much I changed it to If IsNumeric(Left(A(i, 1), 6)) And InStr(A(i, 1), "Totals:") < 1  and gave me perfect result

Comment: @MacroMan Actually, I didn't look at the Demo code very carefully.  As soon as I saw it was using a formula to do the calculation I assumed poor performance. After looking at it again, I realized it would have better performance than I thought at first. Being curious, I put it to the test on 1,000,000 rows. Results gave 3720 ms vs 1940 ms, Demo vs Demo2 respectively.  So Demo2 improves performance by about 48%.  Interestingly; however, by removing `r.Offset(0, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value` Demo reached speeds of around 1900-2000 ms, possibly being the fastest method but leaving active calcs.

Comment: @MacroMan So that being said, for all intents and purposes they really have about the same performance. Demo's use of formulas is actually quite efficient, however, the need to reassign static values makes it slightly slower overall.  Performance aside, the Demo code is nice and succinct, but for that same reason is also less flexible. IMHO, Demo2 uses a better programming paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A4,6))),A4,B3)` is checking the cell in column A.  If this cell starts with four numbers, then return the value in `A4`, otherwise, repeat the data from the cell above.

Can you clarify the second question?  `If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6))` is the same in VBA as the formula in Excel.  The second part (`0 = InStr...`) is checking to see if the cell has "Totals:" inside it.  If it does *not*, then continue on with the if statement (if your cell *does* have "Totals:", then `1` will be returned, and the `If` statement won't continue).

Comment: There are two kinds of values in column A they are like "002323 SomeCompany name" and "002323 Totals:" since the above formula with IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) is looking for all the values that is having first 6 values numeric this will give an error that is why I have edited like If   IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) And 0 = InStr(r, "Totals:") so it will ignore all the rows that is having word Total: in it. if in first code I add  0 = InStr(r, "Totals:") will give me correct result , but I want same change in Demo() since it executes fast